# How to check if an alert is open using nodejs webdriver (wd)

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, remotewebdriver

I am struggling writing a test; in which I want to check if an alert exists, check its text if it does and accept it.

I checked [How to wait for an alert in Selenium webdriver ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639280/how-to-wait-for-an-alert-in-selenium-webdriver), [How to check if an alert exists using WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467471/how-to-check-if-an-alert-exists-using-webdriver-with-java) and [selenium 2.4.0, how to check for presence of an alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076758/selenium-2-4-0-how-to-check-for-presence-of-an-alert), but I fail to adapt it using https://github.com/admc/wd

I have written something along

```
browser.alertText(function (err, text) {
  if (text) {
    browser.acceptAlert(function () {
      // ...
    });
  }
});
```

It works tremendously well when an alert is displayed, but `alertText` hangs when there is no alert window.

How can I check if the alert exists before issuing `alertText`?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may help - this is how I detect an alert using Selenium Webdriver for node.js:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var url = "http://web-page-to-test-for-alert";

driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
    build();

driver.get(url);

driver.switchTo().alert().then(
  function() {
    console.log("alert detected");
  },
  function() {
    console.log("no alert detected");
  }
);

driver.quit();
```

'then' is related to promises:  then(success, failure)

and this may also help - it's how I ignore any alert that presents on a page:

```
function ignoreAlert(driver) {
  // detect and accept any alert
  driver.switchTo().alert().then(function() {
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();}, 
    function(){});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set ignoreSynchronization if you're navigating to a non angular app:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.get(url);
browser.switchTo().alert().then(function() {
    browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
}, function(){});
browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
```